why is (2>3 == False) False and ((2>3) == False) True
I tried
print (2>3 == False)

with result
False

and
print ((2>3) == False)

with result
True

precedence is equal. so evaluate from  left to right , assignment from right to left.
maybe it's a chaining problem (2>3) and (3==False)?

See section 6.10 of the language reference. 2>3==False is evaluated as ((2>3) and (3 == False)), which is False.

Yes, it's a chaining problem as you surmise at the end.

It is because of the chaining comparison operators in Python. Basically
2 > 3 == False

is the same as:
(2 > 3) and (3 == False)  # False and False

Like how
1 < 2 < 3

is the same as
(1 < 2) and (2 < 3)

